# How to get the upload speed from cURL?

Tags: linux, curl, awk, grep, cut

When I run below curl upload command it gives me big output. How can I cut short this to just show the final upload speed?

```
curl --upload-file /tmp/testlocal -v -u tu**r:******@*23 http://nexus3-core:8081/nexus3/repository/tes******/tes*****
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
*   Trying 172.30.51.207...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
* Connected to nexus3-core (172.30.51.207) port 8081 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'tu****'
> PUT /nexus3/repository/testu****/tes**** HTTP/1.1
> Host: nexus3-core:8081
> Authorization: Basic dHVzZXI6VHVzZXJAMTIz
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1048576000
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
* Expire in 1000 ms for 0 (transfer 0x558e6c881f50)
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
} [41940 bytes data]

  4 1000M    0     0    4 45.5M      0  50.7M  0:00:19 --:--:--  0:00:19 50.6M
  8 1000M    0     0    8 89.7M      0  47.3M  0:00:21  0:00:01  0:00:20 47.2M
 13 1000M    0     0   13  139M      0  48.2M  0:00:20  0:00:02  0:00:18 48.2M
 19 1000M    0     0   19  193M      0  49.6M  0:00:20  0:00:03  0:00:17 49.6M
 23 1000M    0     0   23  234M      0  47.9M  0:00:20  0:00:04  0:00:16 47.9M
 29 1000M    0     0   29  291M      0  49.4M  0:00:20  0:00:05  0:00:15 49.2M
 34 1000M    0     0   34  346M      0  50.1M  0:00:19  0:00:06  0:00:13 51.2M
 40 1000M    0     0   40  408M      0  51.7M  0:00:19  0:00:07  0:00:12 53.8M
 46 1000M    0     0   46  465M      0  52.3M  0:00:19  0:00:08  0:00:11 54.3M
 52 1000M    0     0   52  520M      0  52.5M  0:00:19  0:00:09  0:00:10 57.1M
 58 1000M    0     0   58  587M      0  53.9M  0:00:18  0:00:10  0:00:08 59.1M
 64 1000M    0     0   64  648M      0  54.4M  0:00:18  0:00:11  0:00:07 60.3M
 70 1000M    0     0   70  706M      0  54.7M  0:00:18  0:00:12  0:00:06 59.5M
 76 1000M    0     0   76  763M      0  54.9M  0:00:18  0:00:13  0:00:05 59.5M
 78 1000M    0     0   78  781M      0  51.2M  0:00:19  0:00:15  0:00:04 48.7M
 79 1000M    0     0   79  791M      0  49.7M  0:00:20  0:00:15  0:00:05 40.7M
 83 1000M    0     0   83  839M      0  49.6M  0:00:20  0:00:16  0:00:04 38.2M
 89 1000M    0     0   89  895M      0  50.0M  0:00:19  0:00:17  0:00:02 37.8M
 95 1000M    0     0   95  957M      0  50.6M  0:00:19  0:00:18  0:00:01 38.9M* We are completely uploaded and fine

100 1000M    0     0  100 1000M      0  48.6M  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:-- 41.0M< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 06:52:32 GMT
< Server: Nexus/3.23.0-03 (OSS)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Length: 0
< 

100 1000M    0     0  100 1000M      0  47.9M  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:-- 41.9M
```

**My desired out put is as below**

Curl upload speed : 41.9M

I know curl prints stderr and I am struggling to get that output with `grep`

Comment: Why are you using `-v` if you don't want verbose output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not *exactly* answering your question but perhaps a better way to get the average upload speed is to use the dedicated option for it? Try this:

```
curl -w 'Speed: %{speed_upload}\n' -T local-file http://...target...
```

That [-w option string](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-verbose/usingcurl-writeout#available-write-out-variables) will then output the average upload speed (in bytes/sec) after a successful transfer.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Couldn't test it(because of the curl command), it should work ok IMHO.

These commands are printing last field of your output's last line.

```
your_curl_command | 
tac | 
awk 'FNR==1{print $NF;next}'
```

OR with-in single `awk` try:

```
your_curl_command | 
awk '{val=$NF} END{print val}'
```

Comment: Hello Ravinder 

 I tried that but it doesn't work  the i have used  |&  and  2>&1 |  

curl command |&  tac | awk 'FNR==1{print $NF;next}'   or  curl command 2>&1 | awk '{val=$NF} END{print value}'

but no luck 

Regards<

Comment: @Samurai, how about without using `|&` and `2>&1`? Simply put curl command and pass it to my mentioned commands.

Comment: it doesn't cut short anything prints the same, that is the reason I tried with those option to send it stdout

Comment: @Samurai, I understand that but when I did a simple curl on my local machine it doesn't needed those options hence I asked you do try without those options once.

Comment: curl --upload-file testfile.tar.gz -v -u ****:***** http://nexus3-core:8081/nexus3/repository/tes******/tes*****  | awk '{val=$NF} END{print value}'

  it prints the same output as mentioned in my question, Thanks for helping

Comment: @Samurai, sorry there was a typo, try instead `your_curl_command | awk '{val=$NF} END{print val}'` and let me know then?

Comment: Thank you @Ravinder, it also worked but I was looking for solution provided by Daniel

Answer (score 2):

If you are always interested only in last line last field, you might combine `tail -1` with `awk` to get it following way:

```
curl_command | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Hello Daweo ,

   I tried that but it doesn't work the i have used |& and 2>&1


curl command |&  tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'  or curl command 2>&1 |  tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'

Regards<

Comment: You can easily factor out the `tail`: `curl_command | awk 'END { print $NF }'`

Comment: Thank you @Daweo it also worked but I was looking for solution provided by Daniel